# Trying to work with JSON - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a `XMLHttpRequest` to get a file, let's say `someData.json` which holds the following data:

```
{
    "language" : "english",
    "somethingElse" : "Hello world!",
}
```

When my callback function from the `XMLHttpRequest` is triggered the data is supplied as `argJSONData`. Now I am trying to work with my data, for example

```
function processJSONData(argJSONData)
{
    var myLanguage = argJSONData.language;
}
```

In this case, `myLanguage` is `undefined` although logging `argJSONData` shows up correctly, so I tried parsing the data into the JSON format like this

```
JSON.Parse(argJSONData);
```

which gives me this error message in my web console

```
TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function
```

so I tried converting it into an array using

```
Array.from(argJSONData);
```

which made a huge array where each character is a hole entry, looking something like this

```
    0: "{"
​    1: "\r"
​​    2: "\n"
​​    3: " "
​​    4: " "
​​    5: " "
​​    6: " "
​    7: "\""
​    8: "l"
​​    9: "a"
   10: "n"
```

(this is not the end, but I think you get the idea)

Any ideas how I can make it work? I also tried replacing `"` with `'` in my JSON file and much more, nothing works.

I am grateful for any help/feedback. Thank you.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` - casing matters; as opposed to `JSON.Parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
JSON.parse(argJSONData);
```

might just be capitalization issue